# Is this function Injective/surjective? $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, \ f(x) = x^2+x+1$

Tags: functions, solution-verification

$$f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}, \ f(x)  = x^2+x+1$$

**Injective:** I think this is injective because $\forall x_1 \ne x_2 \in f: \mathbb{Z} \implies f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$ for example taking the numbers $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$
$$0 \to 1 \\ 1 \to 3 \\2 \to 7 \\ 3 \to 13 \\4 \to 21$$
**Surjective:** I think this is not surjective because the zero of the second set it will never be reached by any arrow.

I'm right?

Comment: Well, @DietrichBurde, testing a few numbers may be a proof. Testing $0$ and $-1$ proves non-injectivity of this function :P

Comment: Well, @Martund, testing a few numbers also may not be a proof. See above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on what @Marcus wrote, consider any $n,m$ such that $n+m= - 1$ (of which there are infinitely many examples). Each such pair will have $f(n) =f(m)$.

Comment: Can I say that is not injective because $x_1^2+x_1+1 = x_2^2+x_2+1 \iff x_1^2 = x_2^2 \iff x_1 = \pm x_2 $? since $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$

Comment: Nope. What we can actually say is that $$f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Leftrightarrow {x_1}^2 + x_1 + 1 = {x_2}^2 + x_2 + 1\\ \Leftrightarrow ({x_1}^2 +x_1) - ({x_2}^2 +x_2) =0\\ \Leftrightarrow (x_1 - x_2) (x_1 + x_2 +1 ) = 0$$ If $x_1\neq x_2$, we will have $x_1 + x_2 +1 =0$.

Comment: Thank you!  :-).

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(1)=f(-2),$ so this is NOT injective.

Comment: In fact, $f(x)=f(y)$ iff $y=x$ or $y=-x-1$; the latter transformation preserves integers

Answer (score 3):

It is not surjective since $f(x)=x(x+1)+1$ is always ODD (observe that $x(x-1)$ is always even since it is the product of two consecutive integers).

It is not injective since $f(0)=f(-1)=1$-